# business network archive have to redeploy again using composer in hyperledger fabric from scratch. after stop and start

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

If I stop and start Fabric using the script `./stopFabric.sh`, the business network container unable to start again, I have to redeploy the network again using composer and start from scratch. same issue in both local or cloud

### Error :

```
Error response from daemon:
Cannot restart container [container]: network [some long id] not found
```